# Can't seem to check off a category checkbox with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've got the following simple jquery test script to test if I can check off a category box in the right sidebar when creating a new post:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log('js file loaded');
  // Check the "Public" checkbox by default
  $('#inspector-checkbox-control-4').prop('checked', true);
});
```

I get the console message but the box is never checked. I have the correct id. This probably has something to do with load order. I'm loadig the jquery from a plugin with:

```
function pu_my_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugins_url( './js/my-plugin-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pu_my_plugin_scripts' );
```

Comment: Are you sure that `#inspector-checkbox-control-4` is an `input` element, and not the wrapper for a custom checkbox component?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. How do I check for that? I just noticed that the click() is setting the checked attributed to checked. So the .click() method is working. So I think the problem is the svg element is not showing up to give a visual indication the box is ticked. I'm not sure what triggers that svg element to display.

Comment: OK, I guess I just have to add some jquery to show add that sibling svg element to the checkbox element.

Comment: The block editor is a React application, and manipulating it with jQuery is just going to cause issues. If you want to check a certain box by default you should ask a question about _that_ so that you can get a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Well, I wanted to create a toggle so that when Category A was ticked, Category B would untick automatically and vice versa while Categories C, D, E, etc. remain as is.