# How can I prevent a user from selecting exactly one of two (not both or none) categories on a post?

Tags: block-editor

I have Categories A, B, C, D and E.

When creating a post, I want the user to be able to check of either A or B, but not one or both and 0 or more other categories. And I want Category A to be checked by default when they open the page if this is a new post. If it's an existing post, the categories should reflect the existing categories.

I initially tried pulling this off with some jQuery but [ran into some serious roadblocks.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414014/cant-seem-to-check-off-a-category-checkbox-with-jquery?noredirect=1#comment604446_414014)

I'd prefer to allow the user to get immediate feedback and allow them to see categories A/B toggle themselves on an off. But I don't know react. Not sure if I have any good options besides writing some PHP code on the `save_post` hook and sending back an error if the user fails to select either Category A or B, or neither, or both.

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dagspt6u/)? Have you found a solution?

Comment: The problem is the jquery does not work as expected in the context of Wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414014/cant-seem-to-check-off-a-category-checkbox-with-jquery?noredirect=1#comment604446_414014

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. I just wanted to know whether that fiddle correctly demonstrated what you're trying to do and whether you've found a solution that worked with the block editor.

Comment: No, I have not found a proper solution to this problem.

Comment: I remembered this and wondered how did you solve the problem? Or did you use a different approach - what is it, if yes? Have you tried using `wp.data.subscribe()` to listen to changes in the editor and mimic that Fiddle's functionality?

Comment: No, haven't had a chance to get back to it yet.